# My logo won´t display on my Prestashop site

Tags: html, css, prestashop-1.5

I am using Prestashop 1.5.6.3, recently upgraded it from 1.5.6.1. After that upgrade I couldn´t make it to display my logo in front-end. In back-end my logo is already assigned but still it is not displayed in front-end. The template I am using is "Simple Responsive Theme" - it looks like this:
[How my Simple Responsive Theme looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRgKJ.jpg)

BTW. I am a complete beginner.

Comment: the address to the image might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

as sriker-ch mentioned if your image shows in the back-end but not in the front-end the path to the image is probably wrong if you could suffice a link to your site i could inspect it and maybe see whats wrong

Comment: I just figured it out. The trick was in adding a div with my logo manually into code.